# How to change activity while get 401 status code in Interceptor Android

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

When I am getting **401 status code** in API then I have to **open login activity**. I don't want to put change activity logic in every API's onError method. I want a global method which used for all the API's. 
So for that, I created one Interceptor

```
public class MyInterceptor extends BaseActivity implements Interceptor {

@Override
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());

    if (response.code() == 401) {

        throw new RuntimeException(" Here you got 401 from API !");
    }

    return response;
}
}
```

Here I add this Interceptor

```
OkHttpClient.Builder builder=new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addNetworkInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    Request newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
                            .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                            .addHeader("User-Agent", "MyApp-Android-App")
                            .build();
                    return chain.proceed(newRequest);
                }
            })
            .addNetworkInterceptor(new StethoInterceptor())
            .addNetworkInterceptor(new MyInterceptor())
            .addNetworkInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY));
```

Now, where should I add change activity call method. One more thing I am calling API using RxRetrofit. I want a **global method for handling this 401 response**. Can you please provide me any solution where should I put Activity change method call?

Comment: Did you find solution?

Comment: No, still I don't find any proper solution but as of now, I implemented as per my question. so in MyIntercepter class, I extend the BaseActivity I called the method of BaseActivity which clear the user data and navigate to the login screen. For navigating to login activity i used application level context.

Comment: @bdevloperI found a solution you can check my Gist which I mentioned below in answer. Sorry for late response I was not active since a long time.

Comment: I did [this](https://gist.github.com/Sanjay-Prajapati/5c592f6f360fe5fe39927bbc39da70e4) way. checkout my Gist.

Answer (score 0):

create interceptor class

```
class HeaderInterceptor implements Interceptor
    {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request orignal = chain.request();
///--------------------------
            String token="your auth token"; //retriving depend upon you
//---------------------------

            Request request =orignal.newBuilder().header("Authorization", "Bearer "+ token)
                    .header("Accept", "application/json")
                    .header("Content-Type", "application/json").
                            method(orignal.method(), orignal.body())
                    .build();

            Response response =  chain.proceed(request);
            Log.d("MyApp", "Code : "+response.code());
            if (response.code() == 401){
                //handle it as per ur need
                return response;
            }
            return response;
        }
    }
```

now add interceptor

```
.....
                .addInterceptor(logging).addInterceptor(new HeaderInterceptor())
                .build();
    ..
```